# URLs to have variable value rather then just variable

Tags: php, cakephp

Using cakephp, I want to make my URL looks nicer.

If I am at the URL:

```
http://localhost/view/5
```

My web page uses the 5 variable to get all the fields associated with that variable in the database. If my column looks like this

```
id | name | extra
5  | stuff| none
```

Is it possible to change my url into:

```
http://localhost/view/stuff
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking to do is implement a **slug**. Cake can [easily do it](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html#passing-parameters-to-action) and there are tutorials and even plugins that help you if you google around.